# How can I use the LAG function combined with a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to use the LAG function in order to display the previous available amount but when the previous available amount has a value_date of "reimbursment" it will keep going to the last one with a non reimbursment type

Meaning that the LAG should be applied on the previous_availability field as follows:

| value_date | future_availability | previous_availability | precise_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Current EOD | 10 | NULL | 2020-12-18 |
| reimbursment | 2 | 10 | 2020-12-19 |
| reimbursment | 3 | 10 | 2020-12-20 |
| reimbursment | 4 | 10 | 2020-12-22 |
| reimbursment | 5 | 10 | 2022-01-18 |
| utilization | 6 | 10 | 2022-01-19 |
| reimbursment | 7 | 6 | 2022-03-18 |
| Limit Maturity | 8 | 6 | 2022-07-18 |
| reimbursment | 9 | 8 | 2025-01-01 |

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a column like an `id` that defines the order of the rows?

Comment: "...to the last one with a non reimbursment type".  It is not clear how to find this last one, because there is no item on which this data is ordered (or that  data is not provided in the question asked).

Comment: Why does the "reimbursment" that comes after "utilization" have value 10? I would expect 6 (the previous row is not a reimbursment).

Comment: @forpas, there is no ID column but there is a date column and all of the entries are ordered by date

Comment: @GMB,you are totally right!!! I fixed it

Comment: @Luuk, there is a date and they're ordered by date, I added it now!

Comment: @HoussemTimoumi: Then you can use my answer as the base for your solution . Good luck with changing applying it to your situation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(NOTE: this was posted BEFORE the `precise_date`  was added to the question)

If you have an index on `id`:

```
-- drop table mytable;
create table mytable (
  id integer,
  value_date varchar(20),
  future_availability integer);

insert into mytable values
(1,'Current EOD',             10),
(2,'reimbursment',            2 ),
(3,'reimbursment',            3 ),                       
(4,'reimbursment',            4 ),
(5,'reimbursment',            5 ),
(6,'utilization',             6 ),
(7,'reimbursment',            7 ),
(8,'Limit Maturity',          8 ),
(9,'reimbursment',            9 );


select 
   value_date, 
   future_availability,
   (select TOP 1 m2.future_availability 
    from mytable m2 
    where m2.id<m1.id and m2.value_date<>'reimbursment' 
    order by id desc
    ) as previous_availability
from mytable m1;
```

the output will be:

```
+ --------------- + ------------------------ + -------------------------- +
| value_date      | future_availability      | previous_availability      |
+ --------------- + ------------------------ + -------------------------- +
| Current EOD     | 10                       |                            |
| reimbursment    | 2                        | 10                         |
| reimbursment    | 3                        | 10                         |
| reimbursment    | 4                        | 10                         |
| reimbursment    | 5                        | 10                         |
| utilization     | 6                        | 10                         |
| reimbursment    | 7                        | 6                          |
| Limit Maturity  | 8                        | 6                          |
| reimbursment    | 9                        | 8                          |
+ --------------- + ------------------------ + -------------------------- +
```

But is is not using the `LAG` function.

EDIT: removed `limit 1`, and added `TOP 1`, because this is about MSSQL.

Comment: I have rectified the query as follows:
--(select TOP 1 t8.future_availability 
 --   from #temp8 t8 
 --   where t8.precise_value_date<t8.precise_value_date and t8.value_date NOT LIKE '%reimbursment%' 
 --   order by precise_value_date ASC
 --   ) AS 'previous_availability'

However, it is not functional, all the values are NULLED of previous and future availabilities and LIMIT is not available to use on SQL Server 18 anyway..

Comment: OK, i was writing a solution for MySQL, and not for MSSQL, my fault.... 

Comment: it's okay!!! Will you rectify the answer pleaseeee?

Comment: @HoussemTimoumi: i changed the answer to have MSSQL syntax, an not MySQL syntax.

Comment: @HoussemTimoumi: in your comment above, change `ASC` to `DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

First: for the quesion to make sense, you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows - I assumed `id`.

Then, I think you want something like this:

```
select id, value_date, future_availability,
    lag(future_availability, rn) over(order by id) as previous_availability
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by grp order by id) as rn
    from (
        select t.*,
            sum(case when value_date = 'reimbursment' then 0 else 1 end) 
                over(order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as grp
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
```

This treats the question as a gaps-and-islands problem. The idea is to use a window sum to identify group of adjacent records; we can then rank the records, and use that information to pass the proper offset to `lag()`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2b63cd3276703dcce05e761ad91a4a52)**:

```
id | value_date     | future_availability | previous_availability
-: | :------------- | ------------------: | --------------------:
 1 | Current EOD    |                  10 |                  null
 2 | reimbursment   |                   2 |                    10
 3 | reimbursment   |                   3 |                    10
 4 | reimbursment   |                   4 |                    10
 5 | reimbursment   |                   5 |                    10
 6 | utilization    |                   6 |                    10
 7 | reimbursment   |                   7 |                     6
 8 | Limit Maturity |                   8 |                     6
 9 | reimbursment   |                   9 |                     8
```

Comment: My MySQL8.0 gives `ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: rn` (but liuckily this is about sql-server)

Comment: @Luuk: the question is tagged SQL Server, where this syntax is supported (I am a bit suprised that it fails on MySQL though).

Comment: I would also not expect it to fail on MySQL, and to work on MSSQL. 

Comment: @GMB, unfortunately, it is not functional, the behavior of table is the same for me..

Comment: @HoussemTimoumi: I don't understand your remark. Which error are you getting exactly? And in which database are you running this query (you tagged the question SQL Server, is it what you are really using?)

Comment: @GMB, Yes I am using SQL Server 2018, I am not getting an error but the table is returned with the same previous content, meaning that it is using the LAG function normally and always giving me the previous field in all the cases..

Comment: @HoussemTimoumi: this works for the data that you have provided, as you can see in the fiddle in my answer. If you have a specific problem, try and reproduce it in the fiddlde, then share the link in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "previous availability", then you can do this with one window function and a join.

```
select t.*, t2.future_availability
from (select t.*,
             max(case when value_date <> 'reimbursment' then precise_date end) over
                 (order by precise_date
                  rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                 ) as the_date
      from t
     ) t left join
     t t2
     on t.the_date = t2.precise_date
order by precise_date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2b63cd3276703dcce05e761ad91a4a52) is a db<>fiddle.

I would expect this to have better performance than the solution using lateral joins suggested by Luuk -- especially with an index on `(precise_date)`.